# Reference Embedded Object in Mongodb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, database

I have a collection in Mongodb( `Users` ) and a collection ( `GroupTask` )
GroupTask has embedded ( `Task` ) objects.

How can I have Users referencing a Specific Task object inside a Specific GroupTask Object?

EDIT::
My user table is:
`Username

Password

OpenIDurl

MemberSince

Role/Permissions`

GroupTask is
`Name

DateStarted

CompletionDate

NumberOfTasks

NumberOfSubscribedUsers

<<Tasks>> // Embedded array`

A task is:
`Name

Description

DateStarted

DateCompleted

Progress`

Each user needs to reference many tasks and each task can have more than one user.
The only problem is that task is embedded into task group.

Comment: Could you provide some examples of the data in your collections? While we could guess at this it sure would be a lot more clear if you included some examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to answer without more information on your application and its access patterns and how you plan to use this data. A similar situation with products and categories is discussed in http://www.scribd.com/doc/47326395/MongoBoulder-Schema-Design

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to embed some of the fields of your user objects into your GroupTask objet, like PK, username, email. And if you change any user object, fire an update in GroupTask collection.